# How should I cache a complex object being built in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm building a website to allow users to create a schedule composed of several tasks.
The schedule and task information are stored in a database.

When creating a schedule, the user can add, edit or remove as many tasks as they want before finally saving the schedule.  These changes are persisted to the database so that the user can resume editing at a later point (if their session ends unexpectedly or they get interrupted).

Every time a request comes in to update a task, the website calls the appropriate method from my data access layer, then re-requests the entire schedule dataobject from the database to display to the user.

This seems like overkill when only a task is being edited.  I want to cache the schedule object and its task list in HttpContext.Session and only update the individual task being changed (or the schedule object when it's changed).

Are there any dangers with my two versions getting out of sync, as long as I only update my cached object when I get confirmation that the edit operation was successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the session is reset, which can be caused by things like updating the web.config, modifying the dlls, even automatic app pool recycling by IIS, will cause your sessions to get cleared. If you have more than one web server you'll have to worry about syncing the sessions across the multiple web servers and the one in the database as well. Personally I try not to store anything in the session where it can be avoided.

Comment: Would you prefer just querying the database for the complete schedule object after every edit of a single task then?  It sounds prohibitively expensive to me.

Comment: It seems like the simpler approach so most likely. I'm not sure what your thresholds for what is a slow loading page and stuff but if it's not fast enough for you then you might need to use something besides the database. It might be worth looking into a distributed caching system like memcached which would solve the problems I wrote above.

Comment: You're right -- I realized that I had to separately update both the persisted copy (by calling the DAL method) and my local copy (by updating the cached object).  Forget prematurely ended sessions, programmer error is probably going to trip me up.  I don't have much experience with database access so I think I'm being overly paranoid about how expensive each operation is.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any dangers with my two versions getting out of sync

As long as you pull down the new state from the server after a successful edit and update the cache then there should be no issues.

One thing to bare in mind is if you are going to allow collaborating editing you would have to introduce polling to ensure your local copy doesn't get out of date. However, from your description it doesn't sound likely.